# Using jquery accordion tabs on my page will affect the SEO?

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion, seo

I've put all the contents of the pages in jquery accordion tabs, I mean like "ABC information", "ABC procedure" and "ABC video", so by default only one tab will be open when the page's open and the other two tabs will be close.

So my question is, is it alright to use accordion jQuery? Will Google crawl all the content I've inside accordion tabs? Will it affect my on-page SEO?

Here's the link to one of the page: http://www.importletterofcredit.com/bank-guarantee/

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's not AJAX tabs, yes it will because it's all HTML. Google doesn't check which block is displayed and which isn't.